# Pass a variable to a variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I'm writing a script to archive files and upload them to some location.

I am having a problem with the following area:

```
while IFS= read -r THELINE; do
   Filename=$(awk -F:: '{print $1}' <<< "$THELINE")
   Pattern=$(awk -F:: '{print $2}' <<< "$THELINE")
   Location=$(awk -F:: '{print $3}' <<< "$THELINE")

   dailydate=$startdate

   while [[ $dailydate -le $enddate ]]
   do
      YEAR=${dailydate:0:4}
      MONTH=${dailydate:4:2}
      DAY=${dailydate:6:2}`
      echo $Pattern
      dailydate=`/bin/date --date="$dailydate 1 day" +%Y%m%d`
   done
done < $FileDetails
```

The `$FileDetails` config file has filename, pattern and location separated by ::. I extract them as shown.
The problem is with the pattern..

I have them in this format:

`Filename_$YEAR_$MONTH_$DAY.gz`, in the config file.

I am also creating Variables named YEAR,MONTH and DAY inside the loop from the date variable.

What I was hoping was that the "Pattern" variable would read those YEAR,MONTH,DAY variables.
For example, when I echo $PATTERN after creating the YEAR,MONTH,DAY variables, I was hoping it would print something like
`Filename_2015_07_29.gz`

Currently, it is just printing a NULL.

First of all, is this even possible?
If so, how?

Thanks!

EDIT:

The variables startdate and enddate are being passed as parameters to the script.

Here is the config file pattern:

`Filename::filepattern_${YEAR}_${MONTH}_${DAY}.gz::File/location/some/where`

The script reads this line, extracts the Filename, Pattern, Location into variables.
Then, it splits the given date into year, month, day.
Finally, when I print the Pattern, I'd like to see these values in it.

For example: 
when dailydate=20150729
Then Pattern should be: filepattern_2015_07_29.gz

The idea is to iterate over the entered date range. (Say from 20150507 to 20150707).

Comment: @EdMorton 
The config file is like:
Filename::filepattern_${YEAR}_${MONTH}_${DAY}.gz::File/location/

If the date is 20150405,

The output for pattern should be:

filepattern_2015_04_05.gz

Answer (score 2):

```
eval echo $Pattern
```

`eval` will expand the variables in the pattern.

Comment: That would work if the pattern was `Filename_${YEAR}_${MONTH}_${DAY}.gz` -- as it stands, you'd have to declare `YEAR_` and `MONTH_` variables

Comment: @chepner, How do you expand variable then.

Comment: @jackman, thanks for pointing. I overlooked it when saw in mobile

Comment: @MaheshKharvi Rather than "unnecessary", I'd say the design is flawed. You shouldn't design a config file around the assumption that `eval` is safe to use.

Comment: @MaheshKharvi Thanks for the input.
But I still can't seem to get it to work. It's printing NULL.
Is there anything specific I need to do with the config file or otherwise?

Comment: May be Pattern is not extracted properly. Echo Pattern after awk statement to see it prints some value

Comment: @MaheshKharvi I'm afraid that isn't the case..
Do I have to enclose the variables in the config file with single quotes?

Comment: It would be nice if you could post part of config file

Comment: @MaheshKharvi Please check the comment on the original question.
I have posted it.
Let me know if that is good enough.

Comment: @MaheshKharvi I should also add that it seems to be working in the command line but not through the script.

Comment: What is the startdate and enddate value. Where are you setting these values?

Comment: DAY=${dailydate:6:2}` contains unncessary `. Please remove it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84584/discussion-between-mahesh-kharvi-and-fenderbender).

Comment: As discussed in chat, please change echo variable=$(   to just variable=$(. echoing statement only prints it, doesn't execute.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS="::"
    startSecs = mktime(gensub(/(....)(..)(..)/,"\\1 \\2 \\3 0 0 0","",startDate))
    endSecs   = mktime(gensub(/(....)(..)(..)/,"\\1 \\2 \\3 0 0 0","",endDate))
}
{
    for (curSecs=startSecs; curSecs<=endSecs; curSecs+=(24*60*60)) {
        pattern = $2
        sub(/\${YEAR}_\${MONTH}_\${DAY}/, strftime("%Y_%m_%d",curSecs), pattern)
        print pattern
    }
}

$ awk -v startDate=20150507 -v endDate=20150510 -f tst.awk file
filepattern_2015_05_07.gz
filepattern_2015_05_08.gz
filepattern_2015_05_09.gz
filepattern_2015_05_10.gz
```

or if you NEED to split out the y/m/d for some reason then just change the above `sub()` line to 3 separate `sub()`s:

```
        curDate = strftime("%Y%m%d",curSecs)
        sub(/\${YEAR}/,  substr(curDate,1,4), pattern)
        sub(/\${MONTH}/, substr(curDate,5,2), pattern)
        sub(/\${DAY}/,   substr(curDate,7,2), pattern)
```

The above uses GNU awk for time functions, with other awks you'd call shell's `date` and pipe the result to awk's `getline`.

If the above is not what you want then please edit your question to clarify and provide testable sample input and expected output.